# What is the equivalent of the ++ increment operator?

Tags: python, iterator, increment

I am trying to find the right way in Python to accomplish the following task (which doesn't work as written):

```
myList = ["a", "b", "c"]
myCounter = 5

for item in myList:
  print("""Really long text 
in which I need to put the next iteration of myCounter (""", myCounter++, """) followed 
by a lot more text with many line breaks
followed by the next iteration of myCounter (""", myCounter++, """) followed by even
more long text until finally we get to the next
iteration of the for loop.""", sep='')
```

Unfortunately (for me at least), the ++ operator or statement doesn't exist in Python as a way to increment a variable by 1, but using

```
myCounter += 1
```

in its place doesn't seem work either when I want to print the variable and increment it at the same time.  I want it to print 5 and 6 for the first time through the for loop, then 7 and 8 the next time through, then 9 and 10 the last time through.  How should this be done in Python 3?

Comment: Is this really a situation that comes up in any real use-case? If so I'd be very curious to see it.

Comment: @polpak - Yes, it came up for me in a real use-case.  I'm printing a bunch of XML messages that each have a message ID.  There are two message IDs associated with each element that I am printing, so for each element in myList, I need to print out long XML trees with incrementing message IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might consider using `itertools.count`:

```
import itertools

myCounter = itertools.count(5)
for item in myList:
    print("la la la.", next(myCounter), "foo foo foo", next(myCounter))
```

---

If you prefer to avoid the import, you could pretty easily write your own generator to do this sort of thing as well:

```
def counter(val=0):
    while True:
        yield val
        val += 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to import less than all of itertools?  I'm still learning a lot about the basics of Python, but it seems like it may be overkill to import an entire module for just the itertools.count generator.  Can I do something like
from itertools import count
(I tried that and it doesn't work, but I'm wondering if there is something similar)

Comment: @RustyLemur You can do `from itertools import count`. The only thing it changes is `myCounter = itertools.count(5)` becomes `myCounter = count(5)`.

Comment: @RustyLemur -- You can write your own counter, but you can't really do a partial import.  You can say `from itertools import count` to cut down on what is available in your current namespace, but python will still import the whole thing.  Usually this isn't a big deal (the imported module is cached -- so with something as popular as `itertools`, it was likely already imported by a different module that you're using already).  If it is a big deal, you can write your own generator.

Comment: Thanks Morgan and mgilson for pointing out how I can import just count.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply use `myCounter + 1` and `myCounter + 2` in the print statement and then outside it increment `myCounter` by 2. Example -

```
myList = ["a", "b", "c"]
myCounter = 5

for item in myList:
  print("""Really long text 
in which I need to put the next iteration of myCounter (""", myCounter + 1, """) followed 
by a lot more text with many line breaks
followed by the next iteration of myCounter (""", myCounter + 2, """) followed by even
more long text until finally we get to the next
iteration of the for loop.""", sep='')
  myCounter += 2
```